# Стандартные dll MVS

Tags: visual-studio, c++, dll

Здравствуйте, я заметил что при переносе программы написаной на MVS C++ на другой компьютер  где не установлена MVS, требуется дополнительно с ней включать некоторые dll из MVS, и даже для обычного хелловорда требуется две библиотеки MSVCP120.dll и MSVCR120.dll. Собственно вопрос: можно ли при создании проекта в VS посмотреть какие стандартные dll будут использоваться, что бы потом не гадать?
И чисто теоретически, зачем вообще нужны эти dll библиотеки для элементарных консольных программ?(в Qt например, вообще целую кучу dll требуется таскать вместе с программой).
Буду очень благодарен за развернутый ответ.

Comment: эти библиотеки - это плата за то, что бинарник будет маленький (что обычно ставят в противовес делфи). Но если в 6 студии это работало, то в следующий МС сделала все, что бы это было не так просто. Также они сделали [Redistributing Visual C++ Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx), который доустанавливает нужные библиотеки.

Comment: То есть за ранее узнать какие dll будут использоваться для того или иного проекта нельзя? В Qt Creator, например там список dll всегда может быть разным, как я заметил.

Comment: узнать можно, если знать. То есть, если посмотреть на список include, то список dll можно узнать. Другое дело, что так просто положить эти длл рядом с бинарником не получается (по крайней мере у меня на версии студии 2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотреть все зависимости можно с помощью инструмента [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Библиотеки о которых вы говорите это так называемый код запуска (C runtime library). Только вот не знаю обе или одна из них. Я не очень большой спец в вопросе но попробую своими словами пояснить. В этих библиотеках находятся реализации некоторых возможностей которые предоставляет язык, например выделение и учёт памяти для оператора new. Поэтому даже самая простая консольная программа должна либо иметь этот код внутри себя (static link) либо распространятся с этими библиотеками (dynamic link). Настраивается это в свойствах проекта:

```
C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime library
```

Answer (score 1):

Указывайте в настройках проекта статически линковать рантайм библиотеку. ЕХЕ увеличится в размерах, но не будет привязки к dll.